# Need some help in understanding JavaScript datatypes

Tags: javascript, types, theory

1. Why JavaScript need datatypes?
2. I am trying to understand that what JavaScript will exactly do by knowing the type of data?
3. What is the benefit of having datatypes in JavaScript?
4. Based on the type of data, will there be any dynamic memory allocation happens OR there is any size limit like how some languages like C have (example: int : 2 bytes in C)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: Why wouldn't it be beneficial to have data types? What do you think `2 + 2` should produce?

Comment: So @VLAZ is it the only benefit we have? I mean, to solve a problem safely we need datatypes?

Comment: Can you explain why it *wouldn't* be beneficial to have data types?

Comment: I am trying to know all the benefits. yes, to solve a problem safely we need those... similarly, I am trying to understand that why JS need to know datatypes and what it exactly do based on a type of data. I am not saying `wouldn't be beneficial to have data types`

Comment: The purpose of programming languages is to program computers, or in other words, organize their memory. Now to organize memory, datatypes are fundamental. There is no language without some form of datatype (the most primitive one being a byte)

Comment: That is one of my question @JonasWilms so, memory allocation and limit will be different for each and every datatype? Like in C, int : 2 bytes

Comment: It's up to the engine to choose a concrete datastructure for each type. For numbers, a 64bit floating point is a natural choice, though sometimes engines might also choose e.g. 32bit integers instead.

Comment: Thanks @JonasWilms I got it. and how JavaScript engine is knowing the type of data with out mentioning by a programmer? I mean, is it knowing just by checking characters like quotes / ascii ?

Comment: There are literals for every datatype (except for symbols), as well as builtin functions to construct them

Comment: No, I think it's better if you spend some time putting all the information here together, then ask a specific question :)

Comment: @JonasWilms and this is the last one:  so what do you mean by "The purpose of programming languages is to program computers, or in other words, organize their memory." any basic example please? My understanding about programming is simple.. it is to solve problems by using machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. All languages must implement some typing system. Javascript is dynamically typed meaning it assumes whatever type you assign to it (ex. var num = 5. Num assumes the type of "number").
2. By knowing the type of data, javascript will know which operations to perform on that data. For example: 2+2=4, but "2"+"2"=22.
3. You most likely don't have to worry about having a memory size limit for the number datatype. I don't know about strings, but numbers are infinite in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management for info on memory management.

Comment: Nothing is infinite in finite storage. there is both a largest number and a longest string.

Comment: Strings can be arbitrarily long I think, but all numbers in JS are doubles, so unlike e.g. Python's arbitrary precision integers there are limits on the size of numerical values. Hence https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt.

Comment: @jonrsharpe nope, the `.length` of a string is limited to the safe integer range, as such strings have an upper limit (though a very large one).

Comment: @JonasWilms ah I guess that makes sense given the thing I just said! Thanks for clarifying.